# How to execute a package in 32-bit mode using dtexec.exe?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created SSIS Package (.dtsx) which is stored on my hard drive. I want to execute it by using command prompt utility.

It is created in 64 bit environment and uses Excel Connection Manager (JET provider). Hence cant execute it as 64 bit.

I want to execute it in 32 bit. Does command prompt have this option like GUI has ?

```
C:\Users\Administrator>dtexec.exe /FILE "C:\Program Files (x86)\AGSFeedReaders\ICICISendEmail.dtsx" /DECRYPT "<password>" /X86  /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E
```

Error :-

```
   Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDB_EXCEL_NOT_SUPPORTED: The Excel Connection Manager is not supported in the 64-bit version of SSIS, as no OLE DB provider is available.
```

**Can I execute same in 32 bit mode using command prompt ?**

Comment: The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810(v=sql.105).aspx) explains how to install and use the 32-bit version of dtexec.exe alongside the 64-bit version. Is it unclear in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install a 32-Bit Version of dtexec.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/ms162810(v=sql.105).aspx