# The version of ODBC source is not compatible with this version of the dataflow

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package which I am running via DTEXec using a batch file, it looks like this:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\SonicWALL\SSL-VPN\NetExtender
NECLI connect -s test.co.uk:4433 -d LocalDomain -u Development -p password

cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn

dtexec.exe /f "\\local\it$\Application Development\.NET Projects\ReportingTool\Integration Services Project1\Integration Services Project1\Package.dtsx"

cd C:\Program Files (x86)\SonicWALL\SSL-VPN\NetExtender
NECLI disconnect

PAUSE
REM IF ERRORLEVEL 1 powershell -file C:\Users\admin\Documents\SendEmailScript_LIVE.ps1 -clientid 2
```

I use NetExtender to connect to our live server, this is so I can push data from our internal server to the live server. If I run the SSIS package in Visual Studio, it works fine. But when I try to run it via Exec, it fails. With this error: `The version of ODBC source is not compatible with this version of the dataflow`

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you running via `dtexec` on the same same machine where you're running via VS.NET?  If not, have you verified that your ODBC client is the same on the other machine and that it's named and configured the same way?

Comment: It's not running on the same machine, but when I do run it on the same machine using the same DSN's, it still fails

Comment: Hmmm...it sounds maybe like an architecture issue (32 vs 64 bit).  I know for some of my stuff I have to force 32-bit runtime when I run through SQL Server.  Can you take a look at this and see if it applies or helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953455/how-to-execute-a-package-in-32-bit-mode-using-dtexec-exe

Comment: Hi, check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have 2014 SQL Server installed on my machine. My SSIS package was referencing 2016 SQL Server. I'm not sure why this gave the error message listed in the title but hey ho. That's just how SSIS roles isn't it?

Previously the package was built in VS2013 which referenced 2014 SQL Server, so I swapped this around in the project properties and it worked.

Now time for the other errors which I am getting

Comment: Ah, OK glad you got that issue squared away.  The way the VS.NET versions are tied to SQL Server versions is one of my biggest frustrations with SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar error message and updated SQL 2014 to SP2. This resolved the issue for me. Hopefully this will help someone else.