# This version of ODBC source in Data Flow is not compatible with this version of DataFlow

Tags: sql-server, ssis, odbc, filemaker, ssis-2012

I have a SSIS 2012 package running on SQL Server 2016.

My ODBC source is Filemaker. I have both the 32bit and 64bit version of the Filemaker ODBC driver installed on the server running SQL Server at the System DSN level.

When I run the package in VS2015 installed on the server, everything works fine. But when I deploy the package on SQL Server 2016 (same machine) and execute it from there I get this error:

Data Flow Task: The version of FM Source (my ODBC source task) in Data Flow is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.

What is wrong?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40106964/the-version-of-odbc-source-is-not-compatible-with-this-version-of-the-dataflow

Comment: Same question with different parameters. I'm not using SQL Server 2014. My package is only referencing SQL Server 2016.